# YACC: optional token

Tags: token, yacc, option-type

I'm making a mC compiler with lex and yacc, and in my yacc file i want to make and optional token in one of my expressions.

```
Expr: Expr ASSIGN|COMMA Expr                                ;
| Expr AND|OR Expr                                  ;
| Expr EQ|NE|LT|GT|LE|GE Expr                       ;
| Expr PLUS|MINUS|AST|DIV|MOD Expr                  ;
| AMP|AST|PLUS|MINUS|NOT Expr                       ;
| Expr LSQ Expr RSQ                                     ;
| ID LPAR '['Expr '{'COMMA Expr'}'']' RPAR                      ;
| ID | INTLIT | CHRLIT | STRLIT | LPAR Expr RPAR        ;
```

The '{' '}' means that its and optional feature. In this example the COMMA Expr should be optional. How do i say that between '{}' it's and optional feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you should use two rules:

```
| ID LPAR Expr RPAR
| ID LPAR Expr COMMA Expr RPAR
```

`'{'` is a literal character. It is normal to write single-character tokens that way (both in bison and flex, since they need to match.) And you cannot use <kbd>|</kbd> to express alternate tokens, only alternate productions. So you will need to expand various productions:

```
| Expr '+' Expr
| Expr '-' Expr
| ID '(' Expr ')'
| ID '(' Expr ',' Expr ')'
```